# Gradle Build Error: Failed to appy plugin[class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin

Tags: java, gradle, module, liferay

Gradle Build fails with the above error. I am going thru firewall and proxy server settings. I do have local nexus repository hosted in the company network.
The module which is failing uses free marker templates and bundles them into a deployable jar. I suspect I am not including the java plugin in the repository.

Comment: Works for me. You might want to provide more detailed steps to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

Gradle plugin resolution uses a different configuration than dependency resolution.

You most likely need to customise it as well. The exact details will depend on your setup and constraints.
See the [relevant documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management)